# running a command in the cmd in the background of a windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, svn, cmd

I'm trying to run these commands in the cmd in the background of my program:

- Change into that directory and type 'svn log --xml -v > svn.log
- Change back to the c:\statsvn directory
- type 'java -jar statsvn.jar c:\myproject\svn.log c:\myproject'

I'm unsure where I should start but have tried this:

```
private void FileSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string databaseDirectory = saveAndLoad.getFolderContentsFilename();
        FilePath.Text = databaseDirectory;
    }

    private void xmlGenerator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string file = FilePath.ToString();
        var process = new Process();
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            FileName = "path to your script file..."
        };

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;

        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        if (process.ExitCode == 0)
        {
            //success
        }
        else
        {
            //an error occured during script execution...
        }

    }
```

The overall aim of my code is to generate an xml file based on changes that have been committed to SVN the command lines that need to run should create an xml file. I'd like to do this in the background of the program without the cmd being displayed.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run program located in in a file at `startInfo.FileName` path, not your script. Save your script that you want to execute to a file, pass the path to the script file to your `StartInfo` object, start the process and wait for its execution:

```
var process = new Process();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    FileName = "path to your script file..."
};

process.StartInfo = startInfo;

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

if (process.ExitCode == 0)
{
    //success
}
else
{
    //an error occured during script execution...
}
```

Comment: Sorry Don't understand the bit about "Save your script that you want to execute to a file, pass the path to the script file to your StartInfo object, start the process and wait for its execution"

Comment: Just create a simple text file named (eg.) `script.cmd` somewhere in your solution and put your commands (ie. `svn log --xml -v > svn.log`) into that file. File is stored somewhere in your solution, thus you know the relative path to the file - pass the relative path to your `StartInfo` object. You can run the script as show in code snippet above.

Comment: When I run it I get an error "Win32 Exception was unhandled" The System cannot find the file specified. Any suggestions?

Comment: Wrong path to your file (as your exception says...). What is path to your file? What is value `startInfo.FileName` when you start process?

Comment: The path to the file is dependent on what file the user selects. As the program will be used for checking multiple files the user has to select the file

Comment: I mean path to the file with your script (eg. `script.cmd`), it is static, isn't it?

Comment: You must replace `"path to your script file..."` with a real path to the script file with the commands you want to execute!

Comment: Then I get the error Invalid Operation Exception was unhandled 'The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to use environment variables.' on process.Start();

Comment: ...I do not know content of your scipt file, thus I do not know why you get this message....

Comment: The content of the script is the commands i'm trying to run at the top of the page

Comment: maybe `startInfo.UseShellExecute = true`?? Please try to think about my posts at least a little bit...

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function for any command, it always works: here you would need to pass two arguments. 1) your command and 2) your directory.

```
 private string BatchCommand(string cmd, string mapD)
    {
        Batchresults = "";

        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + cmd);
        procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = mapD;
        // The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
        // This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        // Do not create the black window.
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
        System.Diagnostics.Process cmdProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        cmdProcess.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        cmdProcess.ErrorDataReceived += cmd_Error;
        cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived += cmd_DataReceived;
        cmdProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        cmdProcess.Start();
        cmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        cmdProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
        cmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");                  //Execute exit.
        cmdProcess.WaitForExit();

        // Get the output into a string

        return Batchresults;
    }
    static void cmd_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
            Batchresults += Environment.NewLine + e.Data.ToString();

    }

     void cmd_Error(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            Batchresults += Environment.NewLine + e.Data.ToString();

        }
    }
```

note that Batchresults is a global string.

call the script as

```
string result= BatchCommand("Your command here","Directory from where you want to execute it");
```

string result will contains details of all result and errors as well

Comment: I'm getting the error around that Batchresults where has to been defined?

Comment: you need to define it in your class..outside the function 

Define it where you have defined TextSaveAndLoad saveAndLoad = new TextSaveAndLoad();

Comment: I've defined it but at the cmd_DataReceived an error is given "An Object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'XML_generator.Form1.Batchresults'

Comment: you need to define it as 

static string Batchresults;

cmd_DataReceived function is static ..